# Can't create WebStorm React project

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I'm trying to create a React project in WebStorm 2016.3.1

It's asking me for a **create-react-app** but I have no idea what that is and I can't find any reference on Google.

What is it and where can I find the value?

[image]

Comment: I think this will also happen if you installed `create-react-app` through `yarn` instead of `npm`.

Comment: Same problem here. I run npm install -g create-react-app and now what? Webstorm still asking the create-react-app package.

**UPDATE** Just closing and opening Webstorm again solve the problem

Comment: created **issue** for Jetbrains team https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25413

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to install [`create-react-app`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html#create-react-app) npm module, before you use this feature.

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

You can read more about this feature on the [official release blog of WebStorm](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/09/webstorm-2016-3-eap-163-4396/).

Excerpt from the documentation :

> Make sure that you have create-react-app installed globally on your computer, for that run npm install -g create-react-app. Then to start your new project, double click on the start task in the npm tasks tool window to run it. That’s it!

Comment: On my win 7 VM besides this, i also needed to run this command to not have MSBuild errors when creating the react app in WebStorm
`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

Be advised this installs python too, check what it does here:
[Windows Build Tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools)

Comment: By default on Windows it will create this under the directory `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app`

Answer (score 2):

I had ie installed **create-react-app** globally using yarn and webstorm failed to find it. Then I used **npm**, not to mention **globally** and its working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

> **TL;DR**
> No need to install anything. Just enter `npx create-react-app` in the create-react-app field & it should work like a pycharm, I mean charm :)

**Side note**: npx is pre-bundled with npm since npm version 5.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I created webStrom react app following this steps.

> 1. Download [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)
> 2. Open command line console and type  "npm install -g create-react-app"
> 3. Create react app project from web-storm.
> 4. Make sure you provided the correct file path of create-react-app ,  by default it is
>      installed in ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app

use
 npm start: to  start development server

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `asdf` or any other tool to manage multiple versions of nodejs, you will need to set up the path to `create-react-app` manually

I'm on mac, so for me the path was

```
/Users/<USER>/.asdf/installs/nodejs/12.16.2/.npm/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
```